# wordpress ajax keeps losing connections

Tags: wordpress, connection, keep-alive, heartbeat, admin-ajax

I apologize for my being little more han a newbie in WP and ajax but I need your help. I'm not sure if it's a bug or it's simply me who cannot manage to find a solution.

I've the following situation.

I've a plugin that displays certain data from a remote mysql server. This data need to be updated periodically.

At the moment I've implemented this through AJAX, more or less, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url: cktn_ajax_object.ajax_url,
    data: params,
    dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
        << Update  UI according to response >>
    },
    error: function(request, status, err) {
        console.debug("[AjaxOnTimer Error] status: " + status);
    }
});
```

where `$.ajax` is calling the relevant php script responsible for retrieving the remote mysql data. The PHP script duration is variable, according to the amount of data it fetches (Let's say, something between a few seconds and four or five minutes).

If I test the whole on my local machine, there is no problem. The ajax call duly and patiently awaits the (slow) response of the *local* PHP server (which is querying the *remote* mysql server) and eventually, upon completion, it updates my UI.

On the other hand, when I install my plugin on the production machine things don't work as expected. Just a few seconds after having placed my ajax call to the PHP server, I get the following error in the console of the browser:

> Failed to load resource: connection lost. ---> admin-ajax.php

and my script fails leaving me no other clue than the word `error` in the 'status' parameter of the ajax call.

Apparently the heartbeat.lock-post is interfering with my ajax call.
Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to functions.php to turn off heartbeat:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_deregister_heartbeat', 1 );
function my_deregister_heartbeat() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'post.php' != $pagenow && 'post-new.php' != $pagenow )
        wp_deregister_script('heartbeat');
}
```

And restart the apache.

Comment: Thank you Sreekanth, but it will not work. I've already tried. Heartbeat API is responsible for handling post edit locks but also the WP's autosave breaks my script's functionality. Should I disable autosave too?
Apparently every **other** WP's AJAX call performed **during** my (lengthy) ajax call is breaking things.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if your problem is solved. But if someone experience the same problem today, i've solved this using the Heartbeat Control plugin available here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/heartbeat-control/.